# Add Windows VM to domain using Packer

Tags: terraform, packer

I'm trying to create Windows images for usage on Azure using Packer. As part of this process, I need to put some files, which are located on an existing VM in Azure, in the image. My idea was to add the VM to the domain, so that I can copy the files directly. However, so far I haven't been able to add the image to the domain.

I've tried running a powershell script, but this gives me the following error message:

```
Error uploading ps script containing env vars: Error uploading file to $env:TEMP
```

Next, I've tried running the "Add-Computer" command directly from a powershell-provisioner (both regular and with an elevated user), but neither option was successfull. With the regular shell, it seems as if Packer is just stuck. Nothing happens after the message `Provisioning with Powershell`. The elevated shell gives me an error message:

```
(12,8):UserId:
==> azure-arm.xxxxx: At C:\Windows\Temp\packer-elevated-shell-617ab2e4-e084-8ef8-f9f6-0d66a82a0129.ps1:60 char:1
```

Does anyone know how to add an image to the domain? Or is there another way that I can copy the files from the existing VM to the image? Or perhaps it is best to copy the files during deployment using Terraform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't been able to solve this via Packer. However, I found a solution using `azurerm_virtual_machine_extension` where I execute a powershell script which does this as well as some other tasks:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "vm_extension_install_srv" {
    count = var.app_count

  name                       = "vm_extension_install_srv"
  virtual_machine_id         =     azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.app[count.index].id
  publisher                  = "Microsoft.Compute"
  type                       = "CustomScriptExtension"
  type_handler_version       = "1.8"
  auto_upgrade_minor_version = true

  settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
        "commandToExecute": "powershell.exe -Command \"C:/setup/provision/first_boot.ps1 -index ${count.index  + 1}; exit 0;\""
    }
SETTINGS
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have never posted here, but I recently had a similar issue. I needed to domain join my packer VM for a software install. I was having the same issue; I thought It was probably related to Winrm after it's been joined to the domain since winrm won't allow you to connect if you are coming from a machine that now wouldn't be part of the domain by default. You can set this flag to override it.

Enable-PSRemoting -SkipNetworkProfileCheck -Force